# Azure Cogitive Search - search.ismatch() returning wrong entries

Tags: azure, search, indexing, azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure cognitive search in order to search over an index and return the results. But for the following search example I obtain all the necessary results, but also results that do not match the filter expression at all.

Filter expression:

`"filter": "search.ismatch('/.*n.*/', '{column-name}', 'full', 'all')"`

From this example, I expect my regex expression to match all terms in the specified column that have a character 'n' inside it. The output returns every result with 'n' in it, but also several additional entries which don't contain the character:

`{"@search.score": 1, "column-name": "123"}, {"@search.score": 1, "column-name": "B-2"},`
etc...

I've tried changing the parameters of my filter expressing using 'simple' matching or 'any' instead of 'all' but they just seem to ruin the output I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to filter results in Azure Cognitive Search using a regular expression to find terms with the letter 'n', you should use the `search.ismatch` function. Here's an example:
"filter": "search.ismatch('.*n.*', '{column-name}')"

Just replace `{column-name}` with the actual name of your column.

If you still face issues, double-check your data and index configuration to make sure they're set up correctly. If the problem continues, refer to Azure Cognitive Search documentation or seek help on Azure forums.